# Incorrect usage of STR() function in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

With this HQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fs FROM FileStatus fs WHERE UPPER(STR(fs.filePath)) LIKE :FILE_PATH
```

I get:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:637)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:74)
```

and with my `FILE_PATH` named parameter, I have the following in a map:

```
paramMap.put("FILE_PATH", "%PATHNAME%");
```

I have no idea why this is happening. To make things more confusing (or maybe it will help everyone out), if I use a number in the file path, like `paramMap.put("FILE_PATH", "%23%");` it works just fine.

The parameter map is passed into the DAO.read() method along with the query. Hibernate handles the rest. Something like this:

```
fileStatusDao.read(query, parameterMap);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can you explain more about how do using this HQL and how do setting the parameter please?

Comment: Isn't it a JPQL query, not HQL (looking at the exception)?

Comment: @axtavt: Hmm... not completely sure. I know that were using hibernate and that were writing these queries for hibernate.

Comment: I mean, is it called via `Session` or via `EntityManager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that I was using STR() function on an attribute that was already a string.

Comment: You'll probably want to rename your question to help others searching through, something like "Incorrect usage of STR() function in HQL" might be more appropriate :)